# Rails API JSON response, change name of method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-api

I have a Rails 5 API that renders an object with some of it's methods to JSON.

```
render json: { rides: @rides }.to_json( :methods => [ :is_preferred ]), status: 200
```

So this returns something like:

```
{
 id: 123,
 is_preferred: true
}
```

But I would like to change the name of the attribute that refers to the is_preferred method.

The output I would like id:

```
{
 id: 123,
 preferred: true
}
```

I tried

```
render json: { rides: @rides }.to_json( :methods => [ preferred: :is_preferred ]), status: 200
```

But this does not work. Easiest would be to change the method name in the model, but that's not possible in this case.

Is there any way I can manipulate the name inside the response?

Comment: You say you can't change the method name, but can you create an alias? `alias_method :preferred, :is_preferred` on the model.

Comment: No..the app (which I can't change) that consumes the API needs the preferred attribute. But in my model I have a preferred method already doing something else, so I can't create an alias. I know, it's a mess, but right know I need some workaround until I can change the app...

Comment: But thanks, I ended up changing the preferred method in my API so it was free to use as method in my JSON response...

Answer (score 0):

You can try with an [ActiveModel::Serializer](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/tree/0-10-stable), then you can define the attribute key as you want

```
class RideSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attribute :preferred, key: :is_preferred
end
```

or use a method to retrieve the attribute value

```
class RideSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attribute :is_preferred

  def is_preferred
    object.preferred
  end
end
```

Using serializers has a lot of bennefits and is so powerfull if you want to create custom responses.